# Effective Client area of an MDI application without an active CView

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mdi

I have an MDI application with numerous docking bars etc.  I would like to know how to acquire the effective client area of the `CView` region without any such `CView`'s existing.

Should such a view exist I can simply get its window size but at this stage it doesn't or may NOT.

Using the following from a DLL:

```cpp
CRect  oCRectClient;
AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd()->GetClientRect(&oCRectClient);
```

returns the whole `CMDIFrameWndEx` client area including those regions occupied by the docked panes.

Answer (score 1):

The CMDIFrameWndEx class manages multiple child windows, including menu bar, toolbars, docked toolwindows, and the MDIClient window that provides functionality for hosting MDI Child windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/managing-mdi-child-windows?view=msvc-170

In VS, right click on the CMDIFrameWndEx class your CMainFrame derives from, and select "Go To Definition" from the context menu. Note the protected m_wndClientArea member. As long as you are in the context of a CMainFrame method, you can readily retrieve the client area of the MDIClient by simply invoking something like:

```
RECT rect;
m_wndClientArea.GetClientRect(&rect);
```

Answer (score 1):

From inside the DLL code you can use the `m_hWndMDIClient` member of the `CMDIFrameWnd` class. It is easy to use because it's public. It is OK to use `CMDIFrameWnd`, even if your application's main window is actually `CMDIFrameWndEx`-derived, as `CMDIFrameWndEx` is `CMDIFrameWnd`-derived too. So the only assumption your DLL will be making is that the main application Window is `CMDIFrameWnd`-derived.

You have to use the Win32 `GetClientRect()` function (not the MFC one) because `m_hWndMDIClient` is of type `HWND`. Therefore your code could be:

```
CRect  oCRectClient;
GetClientRect(((CMDIFrameWnd*)AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd())->m_hWndMDIClient, oCRectClient);
```